# Fedora 21 entry missing from grub

Tags: 14.04, grub2

I was using fedora 21 and ubuntu 14 on dual boot.

I did not notice when it happened, but now my fedora is missing from the grub entry(ubuntu grub is working) and I am not able to access it.

I doubt,when I installed updates of around 900MB in ubuntu, after that it is missing.

Any idea, what may be the reason and how can I get back the entry of fedora in grub.

Comment: If you EFI boot you need to select which os to boot in your BIOS

Comment: I want fedora entry in my grub. Is there any way. Also I have lot of data in Fedora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `sudo update-grub` detect fedora 21?

There is also a GUI program for grub repair called [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair
boot-repair
```

Run the recommended repair. If that doesn't work, boot-repair generates a log which might point out the issue.